# Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props was not found

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I have an error while trying to build the .net project solution. The error is

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

How to solve this issue?
I tried solving in visual-studio-2015 and visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 0):

According your error info, it sames your project is created by old visual studio version, then build it with vs 2017, To solve this issue, try to create a new Windows Application Packaging project With Visual Studio 2017 and copy your code to the new project.

If this solution could not solve your issue please share your .wapproj file with us.

Answer (score 0):

This was a path issue. I Removed Visual studio 2015 and I ensure msbuild is in the proper location with latest UWP package.